# How to modify the font size in GitBook?

Tags: gitbook

As the title says, there's a preference called "Edit Configuration" in the [GitBook](https://www.gitbook.io/) Editor,
it says that you should use json to build a `book.json`.

How can I write this file to modify the font size? Having searched it on the web, I hardly found any useful articles.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on how you're planning to publish. From the ["How to use it" section](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook#how-to-use-it):

> Here are the options that can be stored in this file:
>
> ```
> {
>     // ...
>     // Global configuration for plugins
>     "pluginsConfig": {
>         "fontSettings": {
>             // ...
>             "size": 1 to 4
>         }
>     },
>
>     // ...
>     // Options for PDF generation
>     "pdf": {
>
>         // ...
>         // Font size for the file content
>         "fontSize": 12,
>
>     }
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: The comment lines shown above starting with // are not allowed in the `book.json` file. I am unable to get a book to publish from the web tool using these settings.

Comment: @RickHenderson, you're correct that those lines aren't permitted in JSON. I think I included them to indicate that I had removed lines from the example. It looks like GitBook has [completely changed the way it handles themes in version 3](http://toolchain.gitbook.com/themes/), so this answer might need to be revised.