# Modifying font size in Gitbook

Tags: gitbook

I'm editing the book.json file to change the size of the pdf font in Gitbook but it won't accept my code and keeps asking me to correct the error.
This is what I have entered:

```
{
    // Options for PDF generation
    "pdf":
    {
        // Font size for the fiel content
        "fontSize": 15,
    }
}
```

I refer to a previous SO question @ [How to modify the font size in GitBook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340812/how-to-modify-the-font-size-in-gitbook)

This code snippet seems simple but I cannot get it to work despite several editing attempts!
I'm grateful for help and look forward to advice to fix this, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json is not valid. You can valid json online at http://jsonlint.com

The correct json is:

```js
{
    "pdf": {
        "fontSize": 15
    }
}
```

In the new version (2.0.0), you can instead of using this option extend the css used in your pdf by creating a file: `styles/pdf.css`.

Comment: Thank you Samy. The json snippet I used came from the example given at "How to use it" @ https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook#how-to-use-it so it is a little confusing that this doesn't work (not valid json). Anyway thanks for your help as using your valid json snippet this has been accepted by the editor.

Comment: Actually this is a great example. Something like this should be in the Gitbook Help documentation.